# DynamoDb model extends from Java entity and this entity has a field of other java entity

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

For example I have a class

```
@Getter
@Setter
class A {
    private String password;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class B{
    private String username;
    private A a;
}

@DynamoDbBean
class DynamoDbB extends B{

    @DynamoDbAttribute("username")
    @Override
    public String getUsername(){
        return super.getUsername();
    }
    public void setUsername(String username){
        super.setUserName(username);
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute("password")
    @Override
    public String getPassword(){
        return super.getA().getPassword();
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        super.getA().setPassword(password);
    }

}
```

I want to create DynamoDbBean that can override or save each fields of A & B class.
In DynamoDb table I need to have username and password column. How can I approach to this?
Does anyone experienced in such cases?

I somehow managed to save the data but when getting an item I receive `null` in `super` object, and cannot invoke getA() method.
Note: I'm using DynamoDbEnhanced Java SDK v2

Comment: The DynamoDB Enhanced client maps data members to columns in a table. I have never seen what you are trying to do and use inheritance. Need to check if that is supported

Comment: thank you for the comment, thus how can I map column to fields? The tricky part is when it has an inheritance.

Comment: Yes - if you did not use Inheritance, it would work perfectly. I am checking with the team to see if Inheritance  is supported.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced#using-inheritance

Comment: Great source for AWS. thank you a lot.